# Notification system

Tags: android, facebook, notifications

I've been looking at notifications for an app I'm making and I'm looking for a similar functionality to the Facebook app. There you receive notifications even though you are not in the App (by receiving something via WiFi/3G).

I've noticed for example that after you restart your phone (and without opening facebook) the notifications still arrive.

It is an important part of my app because it is used to display alerts of failures on a machine.

Anyone knows how to do that or what material I should read for that?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud messaging user notifications does this.

http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications is what you're looking for.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Google Cloud Messaging.  It will send broadcast to your device in which you can decide if to raise a notification or not

Answer (score 1):

refer to this link :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html
try this out !!